# Adding and Setting Text to Content Controls within Repeating Section Content Control

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have a word template that is filled in with information from an Access database and part of that template includes a table with two cells, type and location, for all attachments for that specific document. Within those fields are content controls, name accordingly, and then the whole table is wrapped in a repeating section content control titled "Attachments".

For each specific document there is an attachments folder that I iterate through to get the attachment type and attachment filepath. I would like to add this data to the Attachments content controls but am having issues with displaying the information correctly.

```
Private Sub AttachmentControl(wrdApp As Word.Application, wrdDoc As Word.Document, attachmentsFolder As String)

    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject, folderAttachments As Files, attachment As file, i As Long
    Set folderAttachments = fso.GetFolder(attachmentsFolder).Files

    For Each attachment In folderAttachments
        If attachment.Type <> "Data Base File" Then
            wrdDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Type").Item(1).Range.Text = attachment.Type
            wrdDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Location").Item(1).Range.Text = attachment.Path
            wrdDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Attachments").Item(1).RepeatingSectionItems.Item(1).InsertItemBefore
        End If
    Next attachment

End Sub
```

The attachmentFolder is where the attachments I want to iterate through are located. For my testing purposes the files within this folder are 6 jpg images named Image 1 through Image 6 but in real life applications will contain more attachments than just images.

Expected Result

[image: Expected Result]

Actual Result

[image: Actual Result]

Is this a problem with my code or am I just not correct in how this should work?

Comment: Are you still struggling with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was never able to get this solved. For the sake of time I just found a different method to display the data to the end users.